# Comparing string values from SQL Server to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to compare string values between Snowflake and SQL Server.  I am having an issue comparing UNICODE characters.  SQL Server MD5 hash algorithm produces a different result than Snowflake.

What is the best way to work around this difference for comparison purposes?

Example Code

SQL Server

```
/*  SQL SERVER  
        LOWER and CONVERT are used to produce the exact HASH format as Snowflake
*/
SELECT 
LOWER(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), 
        HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST('md5_alg“test”' AS VARCHAR(50)))
    , 2)
) AS mismatch;
SELECT 
LOWER(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), 
        HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST('md5_algtest' AS VARCHAR(50)))
    , 2)
) AS matches;
```

Snowflake

```
/*  SNOWFLAKE   */
SELECT md5('md5_alg“test”') AS mismatch;
SELECT md5('md5_algtest') AS match;
```

Comment: `varchar` is a non-Unicode data type in SQL Server, is it not? Have you tried using `nvarchar` on the SQL Server side?

Comment: That's a great idea Greg!  I did try that previously, but it didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server uses UTF-16 encoding to store unicode characters. Snowflake stores all data in the UTF-8 character set.

So you need to convert 'md5_alg“test”' to UTF-8 and calculate the hash.

I found a function to do this: https://gist.github.com/sevaa/f084a0a5a994c3bc28e518d5c708d5f6

```
create function [dbo].[ToUTF8](@s nvarchar(max))
returns varbinary(max)
as
begin
    declare @i int = 1, @n int = datalength(@s)/2, @r varbinary(max) = 0x, @c int, @c2 int, @d varbinary(4)
    while @i <= @n
    begin
        set @c = unicode(substring(@s, @i, 1))
        if (@c & 0xFC00) = 0xD800
        begin
            set @i += 1
            if @i > @n
                return cast(cast('Malformed UTF-16 - two nchar sequence cut short' as int) as varbinary)
            set @c2 = unicode(substring(@s, @i, 1))
            if (@c2 & 0xFC00) <> 0xDC00
                return cast(cast('Malformed UTF-16 - continuation missing in a two nchar sequence' as int) as varbinary)
            set @c = (((@c & 0x3FF) * 0x400) | (@c2 & 0x3FF)) + 0x10000
        end

        if @c < 0x80
            set @d = cast(@c as binary(1))
        if @c >= 0x80 and @c < 0x800 
            set @d = cast(((@c * 4) & 0xFF00) | (@c & 0x3F) | 0xC080 as binary(2))
        if @c >= 0x800 and @c < 0x10000
            set @d = cast(((@c * 0x10) & 0xFF0000) | ((@c * 4) & 0x3F00) | (@c & 0x3F) | 0xe08080 as binary(3))
        if @c >= 0x10000
            set @d = cast(((@c * 0x40) & 0xFF000000) | ((@c * 0x10) & 0x3F0000) | ((@c * 4) & 0x3F00) | (@c & 0x3F) | 0xf0808080 as binary(4))
            
        set @r += @d
        set @i += 1
    end
    return @r
end
```

After you creat this function, you can calculate MD5 and it will produce the same value with Snowflake:

```
SELECT 
LOWER(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 
        HASHBYTES('MD5', [dbo].[ToUTF8]('md5_alg“test”')  )
    , 2)
) AS mismatch,
LOWER(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 
        HASHBYTES('MD5',  [dbo].[ToUTF8]('md5_algtest')  )
    , 2)
) AS matches;
```

| mismatch | matches |
| --- | --- |
| 80381678898496aba31245b01f40dd25 | cb95937a11e610f6aaf0d06666bde771 |

Comment: Thanks!  That does work.  Does it make any sense to try to write a Javascript function on Snowflake to go from UTF-8 to UTF-16?

Comment: You may try and see which one is faster https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-convert-UTF-8-text-to-UTF-16-in-Snowflake

Comment: I did come across that solution for Snowflake, but it does not seem to work for producing the same hash value.  I'm confused because the author of that page specifically calls out that this is done for the purposes of comparing a hash value.  Did you have the same experience?

Snowflake

select md5( convert_to_utf16('md5_alg“test”' ) );

SQL Server

SELECT
LOWER(
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), 
  HASHBYTES('MD5', 'md5_alg“test”' )
 , 2)
)

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2019 forward the following solution works for me.

```
SELECT 
LOWER(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), 
        HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST('md5_alg“test”' AS VARCHAR(50)))
    , 2)
) AS mismatch,
LOWER(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), 
        HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST('md5_alg“test”' AS VARCHAR(50)) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8)
    , 2)
) AS match
```

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928